# Why Flex (flash) containing websites in HTTPS (SSL) shows mixed-content warning?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, ssl, https

My website uses html & Flex (sdk v. 4.6.0).

It must run only via HTTPS:// (SSL/TLS).

All the HTML links are prefixed with https:// (and even all other URLs).

The browser shows yellow warning [image: security-warning-screenshot]

The symptom exists even when the Flex is reduced to virtually nothing (see below).

Plain HTML (without flex) has nice padlock icon, without warning signs.

(The SSL certificate was bought & installed yesterday, without EV. Server running Apache, browsers up-to-date: FF, Chrome, Chromium; OS: Windows & ubuntu)

I don't see any HTTP:// calls in firebug (or chromes' thing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="Hello" fontSize="70" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10" />
</s:Application>
```

How can I force Flex to use HTTPS only?  Is it a bug in Flex plugins?

Is there a way around it (besides thrashing adobe altogether, which is going to happen, but not just now)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at FireFox's  Security Console to see what it is reporting for your page load... Also since Chrome dropped mixed-content reporting in v46, does it report secure or http (green lock or gray document).

Comment: the problem was mysteriously fixed by a flash guru, and I don't have any access to this project anymore. case closed. thanks anyway